# Using npm modules in React Native projects

Tags: npm, react-native

Is it possible to use npm modules with React Native projects directly, like one uses them within a React project by `npm install <module-name>`?

Of course I mean modules that can be used with a React app, that is front-end ones that will be run in the browsers JS runtime but not in the nodejs or iojs runtime as a React Native app does not run in the nodejs or iojs runtime.

Comment: now it's 2017, any update?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Well, it's quite opposite. React Native actually runs within io.js runtime so most pure javascript modules for node will work. On the other hand most front-end modules written for React.js will not work for React-Native.

React Native does not use HTML DOM nor CSS as we know it from the web. It replaces the CSS/HTML DOM with the native view representation. So any front-end packages that are supposed to use HTML and be displayed in browser will not work.

On the other hand, any modules that are pure javascript and run within node.js/io.js are perfectly OK to be run in react-native.

For example, I am quite sure that Facebook uses their 'relay' data access library in their react-native apps (it's a javascript library that efficiently communicates over Facebook's Open Graph API and allows to access Facebook user's data).

The way to do it is the same as in other node.js/io.js apps. Simply run

> npm install **module** --save

and you are done (package.json will be automatically update with the dependency for the module). Then you can use the package as usual.

Comment: By front end libs I meant js, without HTML, css ones like superagent, socket.io etc. Excluded http servers and wrappers of sort like Koa, express, since they run in iojs runtime. But if a react native app on a mobile device runs in a iojs runtime, js parts, and which I think not, backend ones will also. But that sounds strange :)

Comment: OK. I see, front-end for me is always HTML :). I know node is mostly used to run webservers, but in fact node (and io.js) is much more than that. It's a runtime for any kind of event-driven application - see more here: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2079190/scripting-jvm-languages/6-things-you-should-know-about-node-js.html . It does not have to be web server, and from what I know about react native is that it's using io.js as runtime environment - for sure it users iojs's require, modules, npm packager and plenty other components from iojs (that's what I understand by runtime).

Comment: React native uses the JavaScriptCore runtime not iojs. So node_modules using in-built node_modules like stream, fs, etc wont work

Comment: @saby maybe it has changed from iojs to JavaScriptCore in between the time Jarek commented, has it?

Comment: Can we use js Tesseract OCR package for React Native?

Comment: From my experience that isn't the entire process, you have to react-native link [module] with your mobile app, and a few other steps.