# JSON Streaming in React Native

Tags: json, stream, react-native

I'm building a React Native app that has to listen on a JSON stream, something similar to node's JSONStream/EventStream style (https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream) . Packages like JSONStream can't get imported into React Native due to platform issues. Does anyone have suggestions on how to do the equivalent streaming in react native?

The way it works in Node is:

```
var request = require('request');
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
var es = require('event-stream');

request(options) 
    .pipe(JSONStream.parse('*')) 
    .pipe(es.map(function(message) { 
      handle(message) 
    }));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using npm modules in React Native projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293050/using-npm-modules-in-react-native-projects)

Comment: @sparkFinder did you manage to make it work? I'm looking for the similar solution. Thanks.