# Using node module with react native

Tags: node.js, react-native

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32293274/981586) that,

> Any modules that are pure javascript and run within node.js/io.js are perfectly OK to be run in react-native.

I need to resize and crop an image in react native so i was trying the nodejs [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) image processing library and i think it should work with reactnative because its in pure node and working with io things.

But while installing it throws errors:

```
PS D:\ReactNative\f_sandbox> npm install sharp

> sharp@0.17.3 install D:\ReactNative\f_sandbox\node_modules\sharp
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\ReactNative\f_sandbox\node_modules\sharp>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "G:\Installed\Node\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modul
es\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [D:\ReactNative\f_sandbox\node_modules\sharp\build
\binding.sln]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (G:\Installed\Node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "G:\\Installed\\Node\\node.exe" "G:\\Installed\\Node\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\ReactNative\f_sandbox\node_modules\sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "G:\\Installed\\Node\\node.exe" "G:\\Installed\\Node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sharp"
npm ERR! node v6.9.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! sharp@0.17.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.17.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the sharp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs sharp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sharp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\ReactNative\f_sandbox\npm-debug.log
```

Is there any fix for this/ whats missing here?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with your app but an npm specific issue. You need to use the right msvs_version flag to install io packages that need node-gyp.

This is not a well tested one but first please find the version of .net framework on your machine.

Next use the version as follows

```
npm install socket.io --msvs_version=2012
```

Note: Your package name could be different